# How to isolate and solve for k in a Sigma notation probability mass function equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, summation, hypergeometric-function

"isolate and solve for k:"

$$P(X = k) = \sum_{k=0}^n {{{K \choose k} {{N-K} \choose {n-k}}}\over {N \choose n}}$$

If the above equation is a function of P, how would the equation be stated as a function of k?

Essentially, what I want to be able to do is calculate how many success, ${{k}}$, are needed for a range of probabilities.

Comment: There is a mistake in your formula. It is supposed to be
$$
P(X = n) = \sum_{k=0}^n = {{{K \choose k} {{N-K} \choose {n-k}}}\over {N \choose n}}
$$
and the question is asking to solve for $n$

Comment: Possible http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772052/how-would-you-go-about-isolating-and-solving-for-k-in-a-probability-mass-functio

Comment: using series (sigma) to compute a discrete probability over a predetermined set and selection (as per choose notation) should be doable. Not sure why  people say it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Tyson Are you certain the summation symbol is not superfluous in your equation? The sum on the right evaluates to $1$ for every $N, K, n$ as long as $0 \leqslant n \leqslant N$. Are you trying to find the inverse of $p(k) = \binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k} / \binom{N}{n}?$ Actually, it doesn't appear to always have an inverse. Could you give us the full problem?

Comment: @YakovShklarov What I am trying to do is write an equation that given the probability, P, how many n's does it take k (in summation) to reach said P. In other words, given the probability of the above function, how many draws will it take to reach that probability. I hope that helps.